# Plotting multiple series from JSON php import to Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

because I'm pretty new to JS, I can't understand how to implement multiple data series into my code

Here is my php page that I use as data grabber:

getTrendData-TIMEREQUESTED-hms.php

```
<?php
    //Define possible Argument request
    $format = $_GET['format'];

    if($format=='json')    {
        header("Content-type: text/json");
    }

    //Define database credential
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username   = "test";
    $password   = "test";
    $dbname     = "test";
    try {
        //Open connection to mysql_db from defined Database credentials
        $connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die ("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
        $sql   = "select TIMEREQUESTED,TS FROM TIMEREQUESTED ORDER BY TS;";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die ("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
        //create an array
        $data = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    {
            $TIMEREQUESTED = strtotime($row['TIMEREQUESTED'])*1000;
            $TS = strtotime($row['TS'])*1000;
            $data[] = array($TS, $TIMEREQUESTED);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
        //close the db connection
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

    catch(PDOException $e)  {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

Than I include in HighCharts with an Ajax call, that call himselfs each 2500 miliseconds,

getTrendData-TIMEREQUESTED-hms.php

```
[[1461241983000,5.67,0],[1461242015000,16.67,0],[1461242164000,16.67,0],[1461242303000,26.25,0],[1461242835000,-2.5,0],[1461242869000,-2.5,0],[1461242991000,1.5,0],[1461243034000,3.14,0],[1461243374000,-14.22,0],[1461243456000,-11.92,0],[1461244995000,0,0],[1461245036000,-3.6,140],[1461245208000,-3,140],[1461245260000,3.56,140],[1461245312000,2.1,140],[1461245346000,2.1,140],[1461245411000,3.5,140],[1461245442000,3.5,140],[1461245479000,-1,140],[1461245757000,-0.8,140],[1461245809000,-0.69,140]]
```

TIMEREQUESTED-hms.html

```
function buildTIMEREQUESTED() {
  var chart;
  var dataSource = 'getTrendData-TIMEREQUESTED-hms.php?format=json';
  var ChartHeight = window.innerHeight;

  function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: dataSource,
      success: function(points) {
        chart.series[0].setData(points, true);
        setTimeout(requestData, 2500);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //add our div for the chart
    $("#container").append("<div id=chart-laptime style='width:100%''></div>");
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        height: ChartHeight,
        renderTo: 'chart-laptime',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        events: {
          load: function() {
            requestData();
          }
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          s = (this.y / 1000);
          m = Math.floor(s / 60);
          h = Math.floor(m / 60);
          s = s % 60;
          m = m % 60;
          h = h % 24;
          if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
          if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
          if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
          return '<span style="color:black">Time Zero - </span>' + [m, s].join(':');
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'TIMEREQUESTED'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'BEST 5 CAR AVEREGE LAPTIME IN LAST 10 MINUTES'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
          text: 'RACE TIME'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          millisecond: '%H:%M:%S',
        },
        //dateFormat: {"%H:%M:%S.%L"}
        title: {
          text: 'TIMEREQUESTED'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'TIMEREQUESTED',
        showInLegend: false,
        //tooltip: {type: 'datetime',},
        data: [],
      }]
    }); //end chart               
  }); //end document.ready
}
```

In that way I can get the single series proper displayed, but with the MySQL query I'm able to get more columns from the database, and parsing in each rows of the json file,(As is showed in the JSON file from php request, there is a third values for each array) but  I'm not able to understand how to display multiple data series, with on the xAxis always the first column of the JSON file, and on the yAxis each time a different columns.

Could you please give me some suggestions on how to display multi series on the same graph? It would be so much appreciated,

Best regards.

Comment: a doubt before I say anything, in `[1461241983000,5.67,0]` data format, the first value is the timestamp, what are the second and third values? The y axis values for two series?

Comment: Yes, they are the y axis values for two series

Comment: so for two different series you need to different arrays. so for one series `[1461241983000,5.67]` and for second `[1461241983000,0]`. and then call `setData` for two different series instead of just `chart.series[0]`

Comment: I can create all the arrays with javascript inside the "function(points) {}"? If someone could provide some example code will be much apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataForTwoSeries = [[1461241983000,5.67,0],[1461242015000,16.67,0],[1461242164000,16.67,0]]; //your data, just took 3 elements. Should work for any number of elements.
var seriesOne = [];
var seriesTwo = [];
$.each(dataForTwoSeries, function(index, dataPoints){
   var seriesOneDataPoint = [dataPoints[0], dataPoints[1]];
   var seriesTwoDataPoint = [dataPoints[0], dataPoints[2]];

   seriesOne.push(seriesOneDataPoint);
   seriesTwo.push(seriesTwoDataPoint);
});
```

And then you'll have to create 2 series in your chart object like

```
series: [{
    name: 'seriesName1',
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [],
},{
    name: 'seriesName2',
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [],
}]
```

And in your requestData method, set the data for both like

```
chart.series[0].setData(seriesOne, false); //redraw after setting data for second series
chart.series[1].setData(seriesTwo); //boolean redraw is true by default, don't need to pass it
```

**EDIT :** After your updated code, these are the changes you further need to make.

```
$.ajax({url: dataSource, success: function(dataForTwoSeries) //dataForTwoSeries is the data you get from the request 
  {
  //var dataForTwoSeries = []; you don't need this.
  var seriesOne = []; //these two don't have to be global.
  var seriesTwo = [];
  $.each(dataForTwoSeries, function(index, dataPoints){

    var seriesOneDataPoint = [dataPoints[1], dataPoints[0]];
    var seriesTwoDataPoint = [dataPoints[2], dataPoints[0]];

    seriesOne.push(seriesOneDataPoint);
    seriesTwo.push(seriesTwoDataPoint);
  }); // draw chart after iteration and not during each interation
    chart.series[0].setData(seriesOne, false); //redraw after setting data for second series
    chart.series[1].setData(seriesTwo); //boolean redraw is true by default, don't need to pass it

    setTimeout(requestData, 2500);

  },
  cache: false
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm tring the code, but I'm getting some syntax error... As soon as I get rid of they I will give a feedback

Comment: I was missing a semi-colon after the first line. I don't know if that's where you are getting the syntax error.

Comment: I've update the code in the answer above and now is free from syntax error, but I have no data displayed. I'm going to put some windows.allert() tu understand where the data flow is broken.

Comment: Now it works like a charm, in effect the charts were redraw itself on every iteration with an impressive slowness.

Thank You so much for all the suggestions, and the code supplied, it's so much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've update the code and now is free from syntax error, but I have no data displayed. I'm going to put some windows.allert() tu understand where the data flow is broken.

Here's the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Strategy - Time Zero</title>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Highcharts/Highcharts-4.2.3/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Highcharts/Highcharts-4.2.3/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>

  var chart;
  var dataSource = 'getTrendData-TimeZero.php?format=json';
  var ChartHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var dataForTwoSeries = [];
  var seriesOne = [];
  var seriesTwo = [];

  function requestData() {

    $.ajax({url: dataSource, success: function(dataPoints) 
      {
      $.each(dataForTwoSeries, function(index, dataPoints){

        var seriesOneDataPoint = [dataPoints[1], dataPoints[0]];
        var seriesTwoDataPoint = [dataPoints[2], dataPoints[0]];
        window.alert(seriesOneDataPoint)

        seriesOne.push(seriesOneDataPoint);
        seriesTwo.push(seriesTwoDataPoint);

        chart.series[0].setData(seriesOne, false); //redraw after setting data for second series
        chart.series[1].setData(seriesTwo); //boolean redraw is true by default, don't need to pass it

        setTimeout(requestData, 2500);
      });
      },
      cache: false
      });


  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //add our div for the chart
    $("#container").append("<div id=chart-TimeZero style='width:100%''></div>");
    //StockChart
    //Chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        height: ChartHeight,
        renderTo: 'chart-TimeZero',
        defaultSeriesType: 'line',
        events: {
          load: function() {
            requestData();
          }
        },
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.y < 0) 
          {
          h = Math.ceil(this.y / 3600);
          m = Math.ceil(this.y / 60);
          s = Math.ceil(this.y % 60);
          h = Math.abs(h);
          m = Math.abs(m);
          s = Math.abs(s);
          s = s % 60;
          m = m % 60;
          h = h % 24;
          if (h < 9) h = "-0" + h;
          if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
          if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
          }
          else
          {
          h = Math.floor(this.y / 3600);
          m = Math.floor(this.y / 60);
          s = Math.floor(this.y % 60);
          h = Math.abs(h);
          m = Math.abs(m);
          s = Math.abs(s);
          s = s % 60;
          m = m % 60;
          h = h % 24;
          if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
          if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
          if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
          }
          return '<span style="color:black">Time Zero</span> ' + [h, m, s].join(':');
        }
      },
      title: {
        text: 'TIME ZERO'
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'BEST 5 CAR AVEREGE LAPTIME IN LAST 10 MINUTES'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {text: 'DAY TIME'}
      },
          yAxis: {
        title: {text: 'TIME ZERO'},
        labels: {                
        formatter: function() {
          if (this.value < 0) 
          {
          h = Math.ceil(this.value / 3600);
          m = Math.ceil(this.value / 60);
          s = Math.ceil(this.value % 60);
          h = Math.abs(h);
          m = Math.abs(m);
          s = Math.abs(s);
          s = s % 60;
          m = m % 60;
          h = h % 24;
          if (h < 9) h = "-0" + h;
          if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
          if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
          }
          else
          {
          h = Math.floor(this.value / 3600);
          m = Math.floor(this.value / 60);
          s = Math.floor(this.value % 60);
          h = Math.abs(h);
          m = Math.abs(m);
          s = Math.abs(s);
          s = s % 60;
          m = m % 60;
          h = h % 24;
          if (h < 9) h = "0" + h;
          if (m < 9) m = "0" + m;
          if (s < 9) s = "0" + s;
          }
          return [h, m, s].join(':');
        }
        }
    },
series: [{
    name: 'seriesName1',
    showInLegend: true,
    data: [],
},{
    name: 'seriesName2',
    showInLegend: true,
    data: [],
}]
    }); //end chart       
  }); //end document.ready

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry, there was a copy paste error in my code. Corrected it. Also, I don't know your ajax call would work without the url. When you make the ajax request , you get `[[1461241983000,5.67,0],[1461242015000,16.67,0],[1461242164000,16.67,0]]` this right? then make the proper ajax call with the url, and in your success callback function. rename the returned object name to `dataForTwoSeries` and place the $.each block inside the callback